# How to get current site theme programmatically?

Tags: sxa

How to get current site theme from code behind? Is it also possible to use `SXA tokens`?

Comment: can you explain more what is your requirements?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following query to get the context site theme:

```
query:$theme
```

Also, if you want to get the site's theme programmatically you can do the following:

```
ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IThemingContext>().GetThemeItem(Sitecore.Context.Item, ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IContext>().Device)
```